# Excel How to input Cell with column letter and row number (dynamic) No VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

let's say in Cell A1 I have the value "A". In Cell B1 I have the value "2". Is there a way to make a reference to the Cell A2 with the value of these two cells?

I was thinking about something along the way of =A1&B1 , but it does not work.

The reason I want this is I want to generate a dynamic row number e.g. with the MATCH() function and use this row number (e.g. A&MATCH() ). Is there a way to do this?

I know how to do it with VBA, but is there a way to do it without VBA?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the INDIRECT() Function:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & B1)
```

If The column remains A then you could:

```
=INDEX(A:A,B1)
```

Comment: @sandboxj just come back in 10 minutes and accept it.  Glad I could help.